# SecurityIdentifier not supported on .Net Core Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm in the process of porting a project from .Net Framework to .Net Standard. It makes extensive use of the `SecurityIdentifier` class to represent identities and to validate identifiers. I've gotten the code to compile and it runs fine on Windows, but when I run .Net Core on Linux the `SecurityIdentifier(String)` constructor throws a `PlatformNotSupportedException`. I check [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Principal.Windows/System/Security/Principal/SID.cs,12ec661268482e41) and sure enough it uses imported native functions to parse. That's not a deal-breaker since I see that the `SecurityIdentifier(byte[], int)` constructor doesn't rely on platform functionality, and parsing a sid isn't too hard. But when I run it on Linux, I'm surprised to see that constructor throw the same `PlatformNotSupportedException`!

Has anyone successfully used this class on Linux? What version of .Net Core were you using? Why does the source code in the link not match what I'm seeing?

Answer (score -1):

When [Microsoft announced the Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/), it was made very clear that anything related to `System.DirectoryServices` is Windows only. If you never subscribed to such channels for news, you should now.

There is also [.NET API Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer?source=post_page-----1b890c74a08a----------------------) to tell such cases in advance.

Comment: Do you know how the platform dependency manifests in the source? It looks to me like the second constructor should work.

Comment: If it looks to you that way while not to Microsoft, you are welcome to send pull requests to Microsoft.

Comment: I'm not proposing a change (yet) - I didn't mean "should" in a normative sense, I meant it to describe my expectations/conclusions. In the reference source for .Net Core linked above, I don't see where or how the exception is thrown. There are functions that clearly have a platform dependency, but this does not seem to be one of them. The whole code path is pure C#, and it doesn't seem to require or use a particular platform.

Comment: @bmm6o The linked file is for .NET 5 already, irrelevant to the exception you got. Please go to GitHub and review the actual source code matching the runtime you use.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure - I didn't see the version clearly stated anywhere. I did look at the git history earlier today and the code for that functionality is largely unchanged since creation.